# How can I allow a user to select a folder where a given excel file will be saved using node.js?

Tags: node.js, excel, exceljs

I am working on project using node.js. I have faced a problem with saving a file to excel. I want to let user select a folder to save excel file (I want to use exceljs for fullfiling it), but I can't find a good way of doing it.

```
export const postCreateExcelFile = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('test');
  const workbook = new ExcelJs.Workbook();
  console.log(workbook);
  workbook.addWorksheet('MySheet');
  try {
    await workbook.xlsx.writeFile('./test.xlsx');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

};
```

This is my example node.js controller with basic excel saving implementetion. Here I want to implement possibility to let user select the folder

Answer (score 1):

To do this in NodeJS, you would need to write a directory service. You could utilize the `fs` library for this, but it would be based from a directory of where node is running. Typically NodeJS is on the server and the user/client interacts with the server via an API, so you would not have access to the client's machine.

Some options might exist in the Electron project, if your Node service was a "desktop app".

If your NodeJS project was a web service, and you initiated the call from a web browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc), if the headers of the NodeJS server response indicate a file type, the browser will "save" that file, typically to the default Downloads location, or opening the "save file" dialog box.

Good luck in your Node journey.